# Is the numerical solution for $\cos(x)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}, x=1.1$?

Tags: trigonometry

I typed $\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$ into WolframAlpha and it gave me the numerical solution $\theta=1.1$. However, it did not provide a step-by-step solution like it normally does.

Is this correct? I know that $\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$ is not an identity since the left-hand side can be negative and the right-hand side is always positive, so I assume a numerical solution can *possibly* exist, but I am very interested in figuring out how one arrives at the solution $\theta=1.1$.

Comment: !!! Can you just one second verify your trigonometru identities?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos \theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta} \iff \cos \theta \in [0,1] \iff \theta \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]+2n\pi$ for some integer $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answers on the identity issue, but the core of my question concerns the numerical solution $\theta=1.1$. Is that a correct numerical solution?

Comment: @Jack It answers the core or your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an identity that is true as you pointed out, anywhere $\cos \theta$ is positive. This includes *any* number in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, or in any interval of the form $[-\pi/2 + 2n\pi,\pi/2 + 2n\pi], n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Thus, $\theta = 1.1$ is *a* solution, among infinitely many other solutions, as WA points out later on in the [page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%20x%20%3D%20sqrt%281-%28sin%20x%29%5E2%29). Why WA decides specifically on $1.1$ is a bit of a mystery, but I suspect this is due to some floating point quirk.

Comment: Thank you. You answered my question. I thought WA was concluding 1.1 was *the* solution. As you mention, it is one of many. Appreciate it everyone!

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, $\cos(\theta)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\theta)}$ is an identity, but only for when the LHS is positive. Therefore, that equation will be true for all $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$ (with the second interval $[\pi/2,\pi]$ cut out, because none of those $\theta$ values will work).